# Extracting Content from Webpage with ParsedHtml

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to use the invoke-Webrequest and the "ParsedHtml.getElements"

```
ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where{ $_.className -eq 'pricingContainer-priceContainer' } ).innerText
```

to try to get the value `$8.29` but using it on the below code produces no result. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="pricingContainer pricingContainer--grid u-ngFade noCenterTag" ng-class="::{'noCenterTag': !showCenterTag}" ng-if="::featuresEnabled">
<!-- ngIf: ::(product.IsOnSpecial && !product.HideWasSavedPrice) -->
<div class="pricingContainer-priceContainer">
    <span class="pricingContainer-priceAmount" ng-class="::specialClass">$8.29</span>
    <!-- ngIf: ::product.CupPrice --><span ng-if="::product.CupPrice" class="pricingContainer-priceCup">
        $5.19 / 100G
    </span><!-- end ngIf: ::product.CupPrice -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By replacing className by class:

```
($html.getElementsByTagName("span") |  Where{ $_.class -eq 'pricingContainer-priceCup' }).innerText
```

or

```
($html.getElementsByTagName("div") |  Where{ $_.class -eq 'pricingContainer-priceContainer' }).innerText
```

An example:

```
$Site = "http://example.com/index.html"
$all = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $Site
# $all contains all informations of the page
$html = [xml]$all.Content
#[xml] is a cast to convert code to xml
$html.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

You can use automation with IE. You choose a div witch contains the Card and you can get the innerHTML like this:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://www.example.com/index.html")
$ie.Visible = $true
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; } 
$html= $ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName('div') |  Where-Object {$_.className -eq "cardList-cards cardList-isotopeContainer"} 
$lines = $html.innerHTML.split("`n")
$prices = $lines | Where-Object { $_ -Match '<span class=\"pricingContainer\-priceAmount\"' }
$prices = $prices | foreach { [regex]::matches($_, '>([0-9.$]*)</span>').Groups[1].Value }
echo $prices
```

Comment: Using the above code returns "Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementsByTagName'."               I did have a go with the below trying to mix things up with class etc above but still returns nothing "   $price =($html.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("span") |  Where{ $_.classname -eq 'pricingContainer-priceAmount' }).innerText "  sry to sound like such a newbie but...... i am

Comment: I have completed my answer.

Comment: And here is the website/html that has made me old, trying to extract the unit price from https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/Search/Products?searchTerm=9314807008734   if you can do , hats of sir

Comment: I looked everywhere in the source and there is no tagname pricingContainer-priceCup that you specified. You display prices with scripts and the command Invoke-WebRequest does not get all tag content like in <main>

Comment: I'm using internet explorer 11 and I right click on the price and choose inspect element. This is the only website that I'm having trouble with , other ones the "getElementsByTagName" works a treat but this website , sigh it will be the death of me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked this bad boy out by opening the webpage , wait for correct html to load over the dynamic html then dumps to a txt file to read and search.

```
    $path = "c:\sourcecode.txt"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true

$ie.navigate("blahblahblahblah insert webpage here")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -s 10}
$ie.Document.body.outerHTML | Out-File -FilePath $path

$pricebf = select-string -path $path -pattern "pricingContainer-priceAmount" | select-object -First 1 | select Line
$Descriptionbf = select-string -path $path -pattern "canOpenDetail --><a title=" | select-object -First 1 | select Line
```